# What is wrong with my proof of Vitali convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Below statement is in The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure, BARTLE, 76p.

**Vitali Convergence Theorem.** Let $\left\{ f_{n} \right\}$ ba a sequence in $\mathcal{L}_{p} ( X , \Sigma , \mu)$ and $1 \in [1, \infty)$. Then the following three conditions are necessary and sufficient for the $\mathcal{L}_{p}$ convergence of $\left\{ f_{n} \right\}$ to $f$ :

(i) $\left\{ f_{n} \right\}$ converges to $f$ in measure

(ii) For each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a set $E_{\varepsilon} \in \Sigma$ with $\mu(E_{\varepsilon}) < \infty$ such that if $F \in \Sigma$ and $F \cap E_{\varepsilon} = \emptyset$, then
$$\int_{F} |f_{n}|^{p} d \mu < \varepsilon^{p} \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

(iii) For each $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta(\varepsilon) > 0$, such that if $E \in \Sigma$ and $\mu(E) < \delta(\varepsilon)$, then
$$\int_{E} |f_{n}|^{p} d \mu < \varepsilon^{p} \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Textbook says that the fact that $\mathcal{L}_{p}$ convergence of the $\left\{ f_{n} \right\}$ implies (ii) and (iii) is not difficult and is left to reader. I seconded it in first glance, but i can't prove it at all. These are proved nowhere, just left 'easy' or 'trivial'. I wasted so much time to prove these.

Please tell me what is wrong.

**Proof $(\Rightarrow)$**(ii). It's sufficient to prove that a case $F = E_{\varepsilon}^{c}$. Take $E_{\varepsilon}:=\left\{ x \in X : | f_{n} (x) | \ge \varepsilon \right\}$ then
$$\int_{E_{\varepsilon}^{c}} |f_{n}|^{p} d \mu < \int_{E_{\varepsilon}^{c}} \varepsilon^{p} d \mu = \varepsilon^{p} \mu (E_{\varepsilon}^{c}) $$

**Proof $(\Rightarrow)$**(iii). For each $\varepsilon>0$, take $E:=\left\{x \in X : |f_{n}(x)|^{p} < \varepsilon^{p-1} \right\}$ and $\delta(\varepsilon) := \varepsilon$. If $E \in \Sigma$ and $\mu(E) < \delta(\varepsilon)$, then$$\int_{E} |f_{n}|^{p} d \mu < \int_{E} \varepsilon^{p-1} d \mu = \varepsilon^{p-1} \mu(E) < \varepsilon^{p-1} \varepsilon = \varepsilon^{p} $$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Questions** (ii) We can't normalize just by putting $E_{\varepsilon} = \left\{ x \in X : | f_{n} (x) | \ge \varepsilon / \mu (E_{\varepsilon}^{c})^{1/p} \right\}$, right? And there is no guarantee for $\mu (E_{\varepsilon}) < \infty$. I approached
$$\mu (E_{\varepsilon}) = \int_{E_{\varepsilon}} d \mu  = \int_{E_{\varepsilon} \cap ( 1 \le |f_{n}|) } d \mu + \int_{E_{\varepsilon} \cap ( 1 > |f_{n}|) } d \mu$$
then the first term can be finite since $f_{n} \in \mathcal{L}_{p}$ but second term  is not. I gave up. (iii) I didn't mention any hypothesis. What i missed? I have no idea how use the condition convergence in $\mathcal{L}_{p}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your approach is that you do not exploit the convergence in $\mathbb L^p$.

A first step could be to first do it when $f_n=f$ for all $n$. Then use the fact that 
$$
\int_{F} |f_{n}|^{p} d \mu\leqslant 2^{p-1}\int_{F} |f_{n}-f|^{p} d \mu+2^{p-1}\int_{F} |f |^{p} d \mu\leqslant 2^{p-1}\lVert f_n-f\rVert_p^p+2^{p-1}\int_{F} |f |^{p} d \mu.
$$
This gives (ii) and (iii): just choose a set which works for $|f |^{p}$: for (ii), take $E_\varepsilon$ of the form $\{x\in X\mid |f |>R\}$ for $R$ large enough.

Comment: Oh, then i can impose that $\mu(E_{\varepsilon} )<\infty$ for all $\varepsilon >0$ by taking $E_{\varepsilon}:= \left\{ x \in X : |f| > \min \left\{ 2 , {{1} \over {\varepsilon}}  \right\} \right\}$ or better one. But still i don't get that how i gain the form $\| f_{n} - f \|_{p} < \varepsilon / 2$ for $f_{n} \ne f$. Since $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $\mathbb{L}_{p}$, we have a large $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \ge N \implies \| f_{k} - f \|_{p} < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ so (ii) is proved if $n \ge N$, but how about case $n < N$? I thought a given $n$ is fixed.

Comment: This follows from the case that (ii) holds for a single function: for each $n<N$, there is a set $E_{\varepsilon,n}$ which does the job for $f_n$. Then the union of these sets works for all $f_n$, $n<N$.

Comment: I feel that $n<N$ part is most difficult. Why $E_{\varepsilon,n}$ exists? We can't use convergence in $\mathbb{L}_{p}$ because $n < N$. Isn't it?